# Is it hard to learn 4D database if I do not have any other database skill?

Tags: database, 4d-database

As title, I am a programmer and offered a job in relation to 4D database work, but I never heard of this one, I did some research and found out it is a kind of old type of database technology that is not widely used nowadays, it is applied in a lot of legacy/law firms.

I am not a database coder or administrator so that I do not have any skill in database area, so just wondering is that gonna be an issue if I take this job? Or is it hard to learn it?

Comment: Asking us to recommend software or provide our opinions on it are off-topic for StackOverflow. Please read the help center to understand what's a good question to ask here, and what's not a good question. http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Answer (score 3, accepted):

4D (4D.com) contains a high level programming environment. 4D Development requires knowledge of database principals and experience in coding/scripting, but the language itself is easy to pick up. 4D delivers both back-end database structures (including SQL) AND front end GUI design. The current active version is "15" and 4D remains in active development, however old code from many versions ago remains usable today. Code is compile-able or run in interpreted mode at your discretion. 4D can run as a stand alone application, client-server with hundreds of users, or in web application scenarios. It is a modern and active product that is also cross platform (Windows and OS X): my favorite part is that a single application can run on both platforms, even simultaneously! It's not the fastest, or cheapest development platform, but it's hugely versatile.